# Simple assignment results in "Tag times in 1 Null is protected" error

Tags: syntax

I've read multiple topics about "Tag times is protected" error, but none of them were struggling with the same problem I am (or maybe I just didn't see it), so I'm asking for help since I'm unable to solve this. Anyone has an idea about why is this part of my code throwing an error?

Relations is a list of lists and it shouldn't be a problem since it's used in the same manner many times in my code. 
Just so you know it's supposed to find out how often does each question occur in all relations (it can't occur more than once in each relation).

The prints are there to make sure that the numbers are correct and they are, so the only line causing troubles is the assignment:

```
probabilities[[i]] = (temp/Length[questions]);
```

My code:

```
(
 probabilities = Table[1, Length[questions]];
 temp = 0
   For[i = 1, i <= Length[probabilities], i++,
    temp = 0;
    For[j = 1, j <= Length[relations], j++,
       If[MemberQ[relations[[j]], i], temp++];
       ]
      Print[temp]
      Print[Length[questions]]
      Print[temp/Length[questions]]
      probabilities[[i]] = (temp/Length[questions]);]
)
```

Comment: Add `;` after each Print statement

Comment: Thank you! It works, but when I delete all the Print statements the error comes back.

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I thought that semicolons in Mathematica are only used to suppress printing the output.